# JRuby & Win32OLE -- how well do they work together?

Tags: ruby, jruby, win32ole

I've been using Win32OLE extensively with MRI to automate MS Office. It works great, but I'm thinking of switching to JRuby to simplify installing apps on users' systems.

With Win32OLE officially in JRuby 1.6, how well does it work? Should I be able to port my MRI-based app straight to JRuby without modification? Any hitches I should look out for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We do have a win32ole extension built into JRuby. In fact, we also sport the [only 64-bit version](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/jruby-win32ole-and-vagrant-on-windows/).

If you do find a bug or missing method or feature, please file an issue at http://bugs.jruby.org/ .